# Counting ACF choices used in custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a custom post-type called "Stores". I've created an ACF field:

- Field Type: Select
- Field Name: store_state
- Choices: Alabama, California, Colorado

I need to query the database and display the total number of stores per state on the About page, something like this:

- Alabama (12) Stores
- California (24) Stores
- Colorado (7) Stores

This is what I have so far... but it didn't work. Can someone point me in the right direction? Thank you!

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'stores',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'store_state',
            'field' => 'choices'
        )
    )
) );
$count = $the_query->found_posts;
```

Comment: This post might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19599531/wp-query-group-by

Comment: Please check out the below answer it might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to achieve this is to create a function to get total posts based on state names.

```
/**
 * A function that returns the total number of posts assigned to a particular state.
 *
 * @param Value $value State Name.
 */
function get_total_post_by_state( $value ) {
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'stores',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query'     => array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'store_state',
                'value'   => $value,
                'compare' => '=',
            ),
        ),
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    $count = $query->found_posts;

    return $count;
}
$state_name = 'Alabama';  // Replace with the desired state name.
$post_count = get_total_post_by_state( $state_name );

echo "Total posts assigned to {$state_name}: {$post_count}";
```